# What should be the credits for score designer using library music?

Tags: film, library, score

I'm making a soundtrack for a film, but instead of writing the music, I'm buying songs from music libraries and building the score. In other words, except of actual writing the music, I'm doing the whole soundtrack from scratch - including planning a concept for the music, setting the right tone, finding the pieces of music for every part of the film and manipulating them to fit the needs of the scenes. My question is, what credit should I get for this work?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sounds like you're some combo of music supervisor or music editor

Comment: yep definitely music supervisor, and if you're personally editing the music then music editor also